# Unable to install Ubuntu alongside windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I have had my windows 7 installed for about a year in a raid 0.  I shrunk the raid to be able to install Ubuntu beside windows 7 but every time I set up the partitions I get the error shown in the image below. It will not let me close the window or do anything with the time zone at all.  I can click OK or hit Close and nothing happens. Anybody ever seen this error.

[image]

Comment: I think this error is with Ubuntu 14.04 and RAID1 configuration, that before asked in AskUbuntu [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/392777/question-mark-error-when-installing-from-cd-usb) but now, user deleted this question.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I format the partition to a raw partition in windows I can format it installing to ext4 and I never got the error.

Comment: You may still want to [file a bug about this problem](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).